# Can't attach solidity-lsp for .sol files in neovim

Tags: solidity, neovim, language-server-protocol

Firtsble solidity-ls installed by mason via neovim command

```
:LspInstall solidity-ls
```

wasn't executable from terminal, altough it was shown as an executable one when typing :LspInfo in .sol file. After I installed it manually via npm

```
npm i solidity-ls -g
```

This is configuration for solidity-ls

```
require'lspconfig'.solidity.setup({
    on_attach = on_attach,
})
```

With this empty configuration however root directory is not found, also solidity-ls is not attached to the file which I guess is just a consequence.
[image: LspInfo from .sol file before]

After adding root_dir manually in a following way and checking the file via luafile %

```
require'lspconfig'.solidity.setup({
    on_attach = on_attach,
    root_dir = function(fname)
        return vim.fn.getcwd() 
    end,
})
```

I get this error

```
LSP[solidity]: Error SERVER_REQUEST_HANDLER_ERROR: "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/handlers.lua:86: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got nil)"
```

Although :LspInfo shows root_dir is set up solidity-ls still is not attached

[image: LspInfo from .sol file after]

LspInfo from .sol file after

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
NVIM v0.7.2

I am new in vim, neovim and lua programming so apologizes in advance in case the question is too silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, "solidity-ls" should be installed using the command :

```
:LspInstall solidity
```

You can find a complete mapping for mason.lsp-config [here](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim/blob/main/lua/mason-lspconfig/mappings/server.lua).

```
:LspInstall solidity-ls
```

Doesn't exist so i assume you used this command instead :

```
:LspInstall solidity_ls
```

In that case, you actually installed "vscode-solidity-server" and thus you should had the correct cmd configuration in your setup.

```
require("lspconfig")["solidity"].setup {
  cmd = { 'vscode-solidity-server', '--stdio' },
}
```

There is probably another way that consist of configuring the default solidity lsp server to solidity_ls instead of solidity that I am not aware of.

Also, you have to be aware of the fact that "vscode-solidity-server" doesn't provide you with a solc compiler. I recommend you to install solc-select to install the last version of solc.

Comment: You can check my neovim configuration here : https://github.com/theCat69/nvim-config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).